# Is it safe to include DoctrineExtensions via the StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, package, requirements, build-dependencies

I'm just about to include the [**DoctrineExtensions**](http://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) to my Symfony2 project.

While scanning the documentation I read about the possibility to include the [**StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle**](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) instead of including it manually. Quoting from the Stof bundles' `Readme.md`:

> This bundle provides integration for [DoctrineExtensions](http://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) in your Symfony2 Project.

Maybe you made any experiences about including via the Stof bundle? Does this always deliver the latest stable release and include all requirements?

Would you rather recommend to integrate manually or with the Stof bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [composer.json](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/composer.json) its:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.2",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "~2.1",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "~2.3.1"
}
```

This means that the current version of StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle will try and get doctrine-extensions between 2.3.1 and, not including, 2.4.

Composer will take care of finding the dependencies you need to make it run. I've included StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle in my projects to use Timestampable without any problems.

I recommend using the StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I also read that in the DoctrineExtension documentation they mention that the [Stof is a wrapper and can therefore be used safely](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md#alternative).

Comment: And stof is one of the Symfony2 members: https://github.com/symfony?tab=members Should be safe. :-)